# underscore template does NOT compile the model I pass in argument

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js-templating

I am doing internationalisation of an app I built. Basically, on clic of a flag an event is triggered and a callback function will fetch a json file containing the translated labels of the app. Then I set the json data to a model. That just works fine. Finally I compile the template with the model and I render it. But I just get a blank page, no error in the console, just a blank page. I console.log the model and the string that template() returns and they do NOT match.

here a simplified sample (the app is originally built in french *):

```
var app_multi_lang_model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    MODE_AVANCE : "mode: AVANCE",
    MODE_OPERATEUR: "mode : OPERATEUR",
    MENU: "Menu",
    LANGUE: "langue",
    FRANCAIS: "Français",
    ANGLAIS: "Anglais",
    CHINOIS:"Chinois",
    ANNULER: "annuler",
    VALIDER: "valider"
});

var app_view= Backbone.View.extend({
        el:"#app_template_placeholder" ,
        template: _.template($('#app_template').html()),
        events:{
            "click #us_flag":"us_flag_clicked"
        },

    us_flag_clicked: function(){

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                app_multi_lang_model_instance.set(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)); 
                app_view_instance.render();
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "../languages/english.js", true); //loading the json file
        xhttp.send();

    },

    render: function(){

        console.log(this.model);
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));
        console.log(this.template(this.model));
    }
});

var app_multi_lang_model_instance= new app_multi_lang_model();
var app_view_instance= new app_view({model:app_multi_lang_model_instance});
```

and this is how english.js looks like:

```
{

    "MODE_AVANCE": "mode: AVANCED",
    "MODE_OPERATEUR": "mode : OPERATOR",
    "MENU": "Menu",
    "LANGUE": "language",
    "FRANCAIS": "French",
    "ANGLAIS": "English",
    "CHINOIS":"Chinese",
    "ANNULER": "cancel"
}
```

[and here are the screen of this.model just before .template(this.model) call:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvon0.png)

[and here a sample of the string that .template() returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQlTk.png)

we see that the model attributes are now translated in english but the html which is supposed to be rendered still in french.
what am I doing wrong? why does template() is still returning the template with the former model whereas I passed it the updated one. And why the browser doesn't display the string returned by template()?

Comment: With `var self = this;` before  onreadystatechange function and `self.render();` instead `app_view_instance.render()`, is it better ?

Comment: and replace `console.log(this.model);` by `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.model));` to have the real value at the time of the call.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what was wrong! the problem is the way I've declared the model.

```
var app_multi_lang_model = Backbone.Model.extend({

MODE_AVANCE : "mode: AVANCE",
MODE_OPERATEUR: "mode : OPERATEUR",
MENU: "Menu",
LANGUE: "langue",
FRANCAIS: "Français",
ANGLAIS: "Anglais",
CHINOIS:"Chinois",
ANNULER: "annuler",
VALIDER: "valider"
});
```

the attributes are not wrapped in "default{...}" so my attributes are not considered as backbone attributes (I cannot access them using model.get). But they exist because I can do "app_multi_lang_model_instance.VALIDER" for example. When I fetch the JSON file and set data to my model using model.set I am not changing my attributes, I'm creating new one wrapped in "defaults:{...}" so my model looks like this:

```
var app_multi_lang_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults:{
   MODE_AVANCE : "mode: AVANCED",
   MODE_OPERATEUR: "mode : OPERATOR",
   MENU: "Menu",
   LANGUE: "language",
   FRANCAIS: "French",
   ANGLAIS: "English",
   CHINOIS:"Chinese",
   ANNULER: "cancel",
   VALIDER: "ok"
}
MODE_AVANCE : "mode: AVANCE",
MODE_OPERATEUR: "mode : OPERATEUR",
MENU: "Menu",
LANGUE: "langue",
FRANCAIS: "Français",
ANGLAIS: "Anglais",
CHINOIS:"Chinois",
ANNULER: "annuler",
VALIDER: "valider"
});
```

So when I pass it to _.template it will populate my html with the attributes it finds first, the unwrapped attributes.

I fixed that wrapping my attributes in "defaults:{...}" and replace this line:`this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));` by this one: `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` otherwise the attributes won't be accessible.

But still, event if the returned html is now correct the browser doesn't display anything. why?